# $broadcast not firing from a service (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to broadcast a message from `$rootScope` from a service which is triggered on a message from Socket.io.
The problem is that it seems that `$broadcast` <del>isn't fired</del> is fired, but my `$on` in my controller isn't triggered.

My code looks like:

```
factory("notifications", ["socket", "$rootScope", function(socket, $rootScope){
    return {

        socket.on("notification", function(data){

            $rootScope.$broadcast(data.something);

        }

    }
})
```

And my controller:

```
controller('RandomCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location){

    function do_something(){

    }

    $scope.$on("some message from socket io", do_something);

});
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Does your code ever reach the broadcast line? If you console.log('something') before the broadcast, does that output?

Comment: @FooL Yes, excuse me, I already updated the question.

Comment: `$broadcast` takes a name & args. Have you tried `$rootScope.$broadcast('socket', data.something)` & then in the controller: `$scope.$on('socket', do_something);`

Comment: @FooL well, the ```data.something``` is actually a string, so I'm using it as the event name. And I thought the args aren't mandatory, but I just tried with ```{}``` as args and I get the same result.

Comment: You are correct, the arguments are optional.  AND sending an event on the `$rootScope` should cause the message on the derived scopes to receive it.

Comment: Try passing in `$rootScope` to your controller & do `$rootScope.$on(...)`

Comment: Try simplifying the name of the event so whitespace is ruled out of the equation.

Comment: @FooL I'm sorry, it was a PEBKAC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This *should* work.  Some things to consider (some are probably obvious, sorry):

1. Are you sure that `data.something` and "some message from socket io" are the exact same strings?
2. Could this be a timing issue?  Is it possible that the message is being sent before the controller is registering the `$on` handler?
3. Is this controller inside of a directive with isolate scope?  I'm not sure if isolate scopes derive from `$rootScope`.
4. What happens when you inject `$rootScope` into your controller and try `$rootScope.$on` instead?  This shouldn't be necessary at all, but it might help in debugging your problem.

Comment: Oh my... It was the first one. I forgot to restart NodeJS when I changed the messages names in ExpressJS, and it kept sending the old ones.

Comment: Gotta love it.  We can beat our brains on this simple things which make us start questioning the complex things.  You might consider checking out Nodemon (http://remy.github.com/nodemon).  It will restart your server when it notices changes in your server files :)

Comment: Ran into this issue.  It was because the other service doing the `$on` wasn't used anywhere yet and thus the lazy instantiation didn't load it yet.  I added the service to the dependency injection of the `$broadcast`ing service and it started working.